# UI Router - Check if a state exists

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want something like this:

`if ($state.get("^")) $state.go("^"); else $location.path('/');`

But it apparently won't work (it always goes with `$state.go` even when there's no parent state). How to correctly do a check if an particular state exists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could use $state.href which will return null if the state does not exist. See http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Comment: Thanks! So this should work as expected: `if ($state.href("^")) $state.go("^"); else $location.path('/');`?